# Using Clustering Index in another function

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I've done some k-means clustering using the built in function in Matlab on some dataset, 500x39 matrix. Selecting 7 clusters. From :

`[idx,C] = kmeans(Data',No_Clusters)`

I get my cluster index, idx (39x1),  and centroid locations, c (500x7).

I then want to use this idx output and my dataset in a Multiblock PCA function that was available online (http://www.models.life.ku.dk/~courses/MBtoolbox/mbtmain.htm). So just say my idx is

```
idx = 5 4 1 5 7 3 2 6 7 1 3 ...
```

for each column in the dataset. I want to arrange it to give me

```
[3,10][7][6,11][2][1,4][8][5,9]
```

where each number in the [] corresponds to the column in the dataset for the  cluster `idx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to determine the locations of each unique index

```
result = accumarray(idx(:), (1:numel(idx)).', [], @(x){x})
```

Essentially what this does is that it uses your `idx` arrray (the first input) to "group" values (the column index corresponding to each value specified as the second input) together and perform an operation on each group which in this case is simply an anonymous function which takes all values in a group and places them into a cell array.